# Python : Assigning image to a variable using loop statement

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I need to assign a image to three variables i.e dsp1, dsp2, dsp3 by looping. On execution, I get a Syntax error.

SyntaxError: can't assign to operator.

```
for i in range(0,3):    
    dsp+str(i)=Image.open("L1.jpg")
```

> What is the problem with 'str(i)' ?

Can any one explain with simple example ?

Comment: Why do you need dynamic variable names? Could you assign these to elements in a list or keys in a dictionary instead?

Comment: You don't need the 0 in range. You can just do `range(3)`.

Comment: I don't understand with list. Could you show it? @Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of generating dynamic variables, place these images in a list:

```
images = []
for i in range(3):
    images[i] = Image.open("L1.jpg")
```

Using this method, the `L1.jpg` is assigned to the following:

```
images[0]
images[1]
images[2]
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary to get closer to the variable name format you are using:

```
images = {}
for i in range(3):
    images['dsp' + str(i)] = Image.open("L1.jpg")
```

This produces a dictionary that has the following layout:

```
{
'dsp2': <image object>, 
'dsp1': <image object>, 
'dsp0': <image object>
}
```

You can access any of these images by using the key (ie. `image['dsp1']`)

In both of these cases, you don't need to worry about dynamic variables. Instead, everything you will be using sits in either a single list or dictionary.

Comment: On adding 'images['dsp' + str(i)].show()' to show the images, It opens the image in the OS(windows) photo viewer. How could i change that to default python window?

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign to an operator.

Look at your code line:

```
 dsp + str(i)  =  Image.open("L1.jpg")
```

You have `dsp + str(i)` on the left side, an expression containing the sum operator `+`. Even if that would get evaluated properly, the result would be a string like `"dsp1"` for example. You can't assign any value to a string.

And because such uses make no sense, Python does not support operators on the left side of an assignment.

You want to dynamically create a variable name instead of hard-coding it. Although this is possible using `exec()`, that is strongly discouraged, as it easily leads to bugs in your code, is hard to read and even harder to debug. It may even be a security risk (code injection) if anything getting evaluated this way is untrusted data like user input.

What you should use instead is a simple `list`:

```
dsp = []
for i in range(0,3):    
    dsp[i] = Image.open("L1.jpg")  # for whatever reason you open the same file 3 times...
```

You create a list simply using the square brackets. If you want to initialize it with some values, simply write them inside, separated by commas:

```
my_list = ["zero", 1, 2, "three", 4.5, True]
```

You access elements of a list by specifying an index value, starting with 0 for the first element:

```
print(my_list[3])  # output: three
```

You can also easily loop over all elements of a list:

```
for item in my_list:
    print(item)
# output:
# zero
# 1
# 2
# three
# 4.5
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just string text together to create a variable name like that unfortunately. The problem is with `dsp+str(i)=`, not just `str(i)`.

If you absolutely must do it this way, you can do it using `globals` like so:

```
for i in range(0,3):    
    globals()["dsp" + str(i)] = Image.open("L1.jpg")

print(dsp1) # This will contain something
```

This will allow you to access those variables as if you had created them the 'normal' way first.

Ideally though, you should probably assign your results to a `list` instead, rather than discrete variable names.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but this is horrible ... uggh :-( Working doesn't mean right.

Comment: This statement will create the variable in the loop but the list created has string values and not the image object, you have created variable list but instead you should have created the image object list. bad answer

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you're trying to generate variable names on the fly.
If I were you I would try to use a dictionary instead of generation dynamic variable names. If you REALLY need dynamic variable names I would go for something like this:

> exec("dsp%d = Image.open(\"L1.jpg\")" % (i));

but I really do not recommend it. Just use a dictonary!

Comment: Even worse that the answer above using globals() - exec should be used rarely - and this is not one of those times.

Comment: As I said: I really do not recommend it. My recommendation was using a dictionary!

Comment: I just think that it is a bad idea to give bad code on this site - lots of people will read this (not just the OP), and they wont really understand why exec is such a bad idea except in very special circumstances. I know you said you didn't recommend this, but i don't think many people who read this will notice or understand  about your reccomendation, especially when you don't give code for using a dictionary. They will simply copy your snippet, and move on.